# Switch between Fragments and MapFragment with NavigationDrawer *FIXED*

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2, navigation-drawer

Problem Solved. Scroll further down!

Im currently coding an app that has a Navigation Drawer. I want a map in one of the fragments.

To switch between fragments in the navigation drawer i have this Switch case:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;


    switch (position) {
    case 0:


        fragment =  new SupportMapFragment();

        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new PlacesFragment();

        break;
    case 2:
    fragment = new LogbookFragment();

        break;
    case 3:
    fragment = new SettingsFragment();

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();



        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

and this is my fragment with the map:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

private GoogleMap map;

public MapFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null, false);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
    return v;
}
```

}

The problem is that i can't switch to the mapfragment. Iv tried to modify the Swich case but i can't get it to work. For an example, i can't get the method replace() to work with SupportMapFragment.

Can anyone please help me with my problem?

Thank you.

EDIT: Updated the code. Still doesnt work.

Error at case 0: `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from SupportMapFragment to Fragment"`.

**EDIT 2: Problem solved!** The biggest error was that i imported wrong fragment. The correct import is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. When i fixed that, I had to change some stuff in my Main activity where i have my Navigation Drawer.

After that were fixed, the map worked, but when i switched fragment via the Navigation Drawer and back, the app crashed. I fixed that with a bit of a work around. Im posting the updated code below this.

This is where the content updates and the fragments replace each other.

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new PlacesFragment();

        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new MapFragment();

        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new LogbookFragment();

        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment with the map.

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

```
private GoogleMap map;

public MapFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null, false);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (f != null) {
        try {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

}

The method "onDestroyView" is what fixed my crashing problem.

Comment: Try this for case 0 `fragment = new MapFragment();` since you are extending SupportMapFragment (which extends fragment)

Comment: While you're here, your `fragment = new SettingsFragment();`, is that a PreferenceFragment or normal Fragment class?

Answer (score 3):

Try this for case 0:

```
 fragment = new MapFragment();
```

since you are extending SupportMapFragment (which extends fragment)

Comment: I belive that fixed the problem in that class. Now the big problem is in the map class. I posted the wrong code snippet. The problem is that my map class is extended by SupportMapFragment. Im afraid

`fragment = new MapFragment();`

won't help now. 

I get the following error on case 0:

`cannot convert from MapFragment to Fragment`.

Comment: hmm. It should work. I have done something similar before. This may not work but try this `fragment = (SupportMapFragment) new MapFragment();`

Comment: That did'nt work im afraid. Been stuck with this all day. Annoying. Got anny other sugestions?

Comment: One last thing I want to confirm, can you try `SupportMapFragment mapfragment= SupportMapFragment()` and see if that passes (in the .replace method). Also are you using this SupportMapFragment http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html or another one?

Comment: Where should i paste that?

I belive i have imported the wrong package, changed it to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Now i don't get any error in the MapFragment, which now extends Fragment. I still get the same error in the switch case in MainActivity tho. :

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from MapFragment to Fragment`

Comment: couple of questions: 1. Is the error still in the replace method?(asking since you using `fragment =  new SupportMapFragment();` which was suppose to be a test to see if it would fail to compile)? 2. is Mapfragment extending Fragment for SupportMapFragment (cannot tell based on you code and comment)?

Comment: Actually got it to work now. Iv imported the wrong Fragment in the other Fragment classes. After i fixed that, i could chose my mapFragment in the navigation drawer and the map showed up. If i switched fragment and then back to the mapFragment it crashed. Fixed that with a method. 

Im going to update my post with the updated code, if anyone else encounter the same problem as I. Thanks alot for your help. I can't upvote you because i don't have enough reputation. But will do when i have.