# How to start another fragment from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

For example, I click on the button inside this fragment, and the fragment replaces to other. Activity remains the same.

```
 public class cat_beauty extends Fragment {

public cat_beauty(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ca_beauty, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Actually what is your pblm?can't get it

Answer (score 0):

You should use your Fragment manager in your MainActivity to do this.

The fragement manager is placed in your MainActivity which controll all fragments with UI controller like navigation drawer or any other implementation.

here are some useful examples you can use for learning more:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176999/how-to-switch-between-fragments-during-onclick)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793576/switching-between-fragment-view)

[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478475/switch-between-fragments-and-mapfragment-with-navigationdrawer-fixed)

Comment: Thanks for Reply .. i understand that but  problems is that .. after display fragment i want to tart another fragment activity from this ..